# Swift - Efficient way to switch between multiple images on MapKit

Tags: ios, swift

I have a small problem with showing rain radar images on MapKit (switching between them every second). Information: 14 images (each: 32-42 KB, 2000 x 1450 pixels).

**Question 1**

I am currently downloading them everytime, yes. Caching on the device itself is on the ToDo. Any suggestions?

**Question 2**

Currently I am switching between those images every 1 second (just a simple timer atm), doing `mapView.removeOverlay(layer)` and `mapView.addOverlay(newLayer)`. But this eats a lot of CPU (around 130%) and memory. The images are also flickering on screen (on my physical iPhone) because it doesn't get renderend on time, this doesn't happen on my iPhone/iPad emulator.

I do store the downloaded images in a class/model (with other information) which is a member of a simple `var rainLayers = [RainMapOverlay]()`.

My MapKit code looks like:
**ViewController.swift**

```
    var rainLayers = [RainMapOverlay]()
    var currentNumber = -1

    func switchBetweenOverlays()
    {        
        if ( currentNumber > -1 )
            // remove current overlay
            let layer = self.rainLayers[currentNumber]
            mapView.removeOverlay(layer)
        }

        currentNumber += 1

        if ( currentNumber > ( self.rainLayers.count - 1 ) )
        {
            currentNumber = 0
        }

        let layer = self.rainLayers[currentNumber]
        mapView.addOverlay(layer)
    }

    func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, rendererFor overlay: MKOverlay) -> MKOverlayRenderer
    {
        if ( overlay is RainMapOverlay )
        {
            return ImageMapOverlayView(overlay: overlay)
        }

        return MKOverlayRenderer()
    }
```

**RainMapOverlay.swift**

```
class RainMapOverlay: NSObject, MKOverlay
{
    var coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D
    var boundingMapRect: MKMapRect
    var theImage: UIImage
    var layerData: RainMapData
    public var alpha: CGFloat

    init (_ rainData: RainMapData)
    {
        layerData = rainData
        boundingMapRect = rainData.overlayBoundingMapRect
        coordinate = rainData.midCoordinate
        alpha = CGFloat(1.0)

        // download picture - TODO: caching
        let photoUrl = URL(string: rainData.name)
        let photoData = try? Data(contentsOf: photoUrl!)
        theImage = UIImage(data: photoData!)!
    }
}
```

**ImageMapOverlayView.swift**

```
class ImageMapOverlayView: MKOverlayRenderer
{
    override func draw (_ mapRect: MKMapRect, zoomScale: MKZoomScale, in context: CGContext)
    {
        guard let overlay = self.overlay as? RainMapOverlay else {
            return
        }

        let rect = self.rect(for: overlay.boundingMapRect)

        context.scaleBy(x: 1.0, y: -1.0)
        context.translateBy(x: 0.0, y: -rect.size.height)
        context.setAlpha(overlay.alpha)
        context.draw(overlay.theImage.cgImage!, in: rect)
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Updating to iOS 13.4.x fixed the issue (question 2).